# Stripe Connect - retrieving access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, stripe-payments

I am trying to set up Stripe Connect for a rails 3.2.13 app. I have directed the user to Stripe and received back the authorization code from Stripe:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://localhost:3000/yourshop/stripe?scope=read_write&state=1234&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE
```

The next step involves making a POST request to receive the access_token via the access_token_url, per Stripe documentation:

```
curl -X POST https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
  -d client_secret=sk_test_code \
  -d code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE \
  -d grant_type=authorization_code
```

I don't have any experience with curl is a rails app and I couldn't find anything in the Stripe API that seems like this POST request is include in the Stripe Gem:

Gem file:

```
gem 'omniauth-stripe-connect'
gem 'stripe'
```

Model

```
def save_with_stripe_account
  code = self.stripe_code
  customer = curl -X POST https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
    -d "client_secret=ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']" \
    -d "code=code" \
    -d "grant_type=authorization_code"
  raise customer.inspect  
end
```

Error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

Not sure if just the wrong formatting for curl in rails or if need to use something else.

Comment: I do not know the Stripe API, but just so you know: [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) is a command-line tool thus you **can't** copy-paste as is a curl command within your Ruby code. At least you need to perform a [system call in Ruby](http://martinhauser.com/wiki/Ruby_System_Calls). In practice I recommend you to use either the Stripe gem itself (that may include what you need) or - if you need to perform custom HTTP requests yourself, use a Ruby HTTP library such as [curb](https://rubygems.org/gems/curb) which uses libcurl or `Net::HTTP` official library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it too work, probably not the prettiest way:

The first thing I learned is that curl can work inside rails if you put backticks around the curl code. This will return JSON which just needs to be formatted. I ended up with the following in my model:

```
customer = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(`curl -X POST https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token -d client_secret=#{ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']} -d code=#{self.stripe_code} -d grant_type=authorization_code`)
```

I then am able to extract the data from the customer hash such as "access_token":

```
customer['access_token']
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this recipe:

install the HTTParty gem in your rails application

response = HTTParty.post("https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token", :query => { client_secret: "#{ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']}", code: response_code, grant_type: "authorization_code" })

Then you should be able to access response['access_token'] without having to use backticks around the curl code.  It worked for me.

Comment: On printing the response i get all the values but i cannot get access_token as response['access_token'].

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [omniauth stripe connect strategy](https://github.com/isaacsanders/omniauth-stripe-connect) then it gets taken care of for you and is placed in the `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` in your omniauth callbacks controller.

No need to do any HTTParty, the omniauth stripe connect strategy takes care of all the things. Beauty!